# NGINX mod _proxy_html available?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy

Somebody created already a similar http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/ mod_proxy_html module for Nginx?

I think the closest module would be http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubsModule but I have no clue how I should configure this to rebuild the functionalities of the apache module.

Thanks!

Comment: It won't be an exact analog to the Apache module; it's a more manual process.  That said, if you can provide your current setup of the Apache module, we can probably assist with mimicking that in the nginx module.